# grails application access after authentication with ldap role based authorization

Tags: grails

Our grails application uses ldap authentication, without any problems, now I need to prevent access, to the entire application, if a user has no specific ldap role.

I can see the role and use it in my Config.groovy annotations or secure the actions in the controllers, but instead I need a scenario/way to just show a "Denied ..." message and logout. (POST Forbidden 403).

```
def filters = {
    loginFilter(controller:'login', action:'ajaxSuccessSproutcore') {
        before = {
            switch(Environment.current.name) {
                case { it == 'development' || it == 'hrm'}:
                    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SEA_HRM_LOGIN")){
                    } else {
                        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
                            render ([msg:''] as JSON)
                            session.invalidate()
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                    break

                default:
                    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_ADMIN , ROLE_USER")){
                    } else {
                        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
                            render ([msg:''] as JSON)
                            session.invalidate()
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                    break
            }
        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grails 3 you can set up an [Interceptor](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.7/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors) to check every request and take the appropriate action.  In your case you'd want to add a check in the `before` block.

Edit: As Jeff Brown notes in the comments, grails 2 used [Filters](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.11/guide/single.html#filters) rather than interceptors.

Edit: Something like this in your logout logic:

```
...
        else {                
           if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
               session.invalidate()
               redirect action:'youShallNotPass'
               return false
           }
        }
```

Comment: "In grails 3 you can set up an Interceptor to check every request..." - That is true, but because the original question mentions `Config.groovy`, it is reasonable to expect that they are not using Grails 3.  In Grails 2 the closest thing to an interceptor would be a filter.

Comment: Correct, I am using grails 2.3.11, thanks for your response, I will look into the filter documentation. In my case we have a new ldap role for HRM users, and only these users may access the application. (We have 4 variants of the application, with each a own database). E.g. the HRM database should only be accessable for HRM users.

Comment: started with the controller beforeInterceptor, but can not find a way to show a denied message/view and logout programmatically.

Comment: What Jeff is referring to is the use of Filters (https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.11/guide/single.html#filters) to fulfill the functionality of an interceptor.  Not the domain specific "before/after" interceptor methods. You can use these to intercept all requests and can `session.invalidate()` if the user doesn't meet your criteria.

Comment: Thought that filters were deprecated, but I will give it a try, thanks. Is it possible to display an appropriate message to the user before invalidating the session?

Comment: Certainly if you're redirecting to the login page, you can set a `flash.message` or `flash.error` and show that on the login page.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bit more complicated, We use sproutcore as an UI on top of grails. The user logs in, is ldap authenticated, and in a grails Filters I test for a specific role, log.info messages are shown succesfull, but I can not find a way to send a message or view , like "Your are not having rights ..." and then resume to a new login or stop the application.

Comment: You should be able to issue a redirect from your filter...  `before = {
              if (<your logic here>) {
                  redirect(action: 'login')
                  return false
               }
           }`  -- Can you update your question to include the code in your filter?

Comment: Thanks for the assistence, but the user is already loggedIn, just because of the missing role the user must/should be loggedOut. I have added some code.

Comment: That was just a sample of what to do...  Edited the above answer to include a more realistic block...

Comment: Edited with my last results, only the redirect part is replaced, it shows now the standard login failed view. And added an environment.  Will be continued next week.